# Unbalanced line spacing for UILabel after three lines

Tags: objective-c, uilabel

I have a `UIScrollView` inside there is `UIImageView` on which there is a UILabel as shown in the picture:

[image]

**Issue:**

The problem is that after first three lines the next lines have uneven line spacing as shown in the picture (i skipped first three lines) from fourth line it has been moving upward. Firstly i thought this is related to the background line image i have placed but after testing it for a while this is related to **UILabel**.

Does anyone know how I can adjust the line spacing to remain same for all the lines?

Note: My **UILabel** have **0** number of lines

Comment: It looks like the space between each line is fine to me. The lines that have been draw on there seem to be off though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used Pixel Tools to make some measurements of the screen shot. Your lines are drawn every 30 pixels, and the baseline separation of the text in this UILabel is 29 pixels.

Comment: THis is the normal UILable :( i havent customized it

Comment: @ghazi_jaffary The measurements I gave are from your screenshot. The line height (baseline separation) of the text is fixed. Every line was 29 pixels lower than the previous.